# Graphviz: route line from the left side of the node

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to create flow chart as shown in the image #2 (with the red lines) but I am not able to position the lines from the left side of the `onset` node to the left side of the `sampling` node. If `:w` or `:s` is added to the node, line is broken and goes from the inside of the node. Is it possible to route the lines like that and put the text to the side so it doesn't collide with the line?

```
digraph G {
    graph [splines=ortho];//, nodesep=0.8]
    node [shape=record]

    sampling [
        label = "Sampling";
        shape = rect;
    ];
    
    onset [
        label = "Onset\ndetection";
        shape = diamond;
    ];

    collect [
        label = "Collect 1024 samples";
        shape = rect;
    ];

    xcorr [
        label = "Compute\ncross correlation";
        shape = rect;
    ];

    display [
        label = "Display data";
        shape = rect;
    ];


    sampling->onset;
    onset->sampling [label = "No"];
    onset->collect [label = "Yes"];
    collect->xcorr;
    xcorr->display;
    xcorr->sampling [ label = "Return"; ];

    {       
        rank = same;
        collect; xcorr;
    }
}
```

[image: Actual]

[image: What I want]

Comment: Graphviz **ortho** splines are something of a botch.  Your goal can probably be attained w/ **dot**, but it will be a slog.  Are you open to using different drawing software?

Comment: @sroush I don't insist on Graphviz but I wanted to create flow chart programmatically for easier graph editing. Do you have any software recommendation, like Graphviz, that can do that?

Comment: @Matej flowchart.fun and mermaid.js are some alternatives